# Zend Framework and SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, zend-framework

I'm trying to use Zend Framework with SQL server 2005 express (through Pdo_Mssql with [wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) installation) but seem that pdo can't connect to SQL. 
This is my code:

```
require '../application/bootstrap.php'; 

try {
    $db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mssql', array(
    'host'     => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'sa',
    'password' => 'verystrongpass',
    'dbname'   => 'msdb'
));
    $db->getConnection();
} catch (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e) {
    $e->getMessage();
} catch (Zend_Exception $e) {
   $e->getMessage();
}


$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table';

$result = $db->fetchAll($sql);

echo "----------------" . var_dump($result);
```

and the error result is always:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with
>   message 'SQLSTATE[01002] **Unable to
>   connect: SQL Server is unavailable or
>   does not exist**. (severity 9)' in
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php:130
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mssql.php(135):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
>
> 1
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(389):Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mssql->_connect()
>
> 2
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(205):Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT
>   * FROM t...', Array)
>
> 3
>   C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(616):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT
>   * FROM t...', Array)
>
> 4 C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Luca\Documenti\Workspace\web\db\public\index.php(27):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM t...') #5 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php
>   on line 130

So anyone have some experience with ZF + SQL server, SQL server need some special configuration? In istallation time i've only specify to use the default istance and to use mixed authentication. Moreover I can successful connect with db through Microsoft SQL server management studio express.

Answer (score 1):

All SQL Server Express installations on a named instance of SQLEXPRESS rather than a default instance - see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165614.aspx).

So your host should look like

```
'host'     => 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS'
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you pls check in you PHP.ini file, that you enabled the Pdo_Mssq.dll

If not remove the ";" in front of the Pdo_Mssql.dll

Dan

Comment: No spam footers please; they *will* be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think your

`'host'     => 'localhost\SQLEXPRESS'` configuration

should be like :

`'host'     => 'computer_name\SQLEXPRESS'`