# Connect to SQL Server 2008 with PDO

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 (not express) with PHP 5.2.9-2 on Windows XP sp2. I can connect to the remote SQL Server fine from SQL Server Management Studio from the same machine.

My first attempt was this:

```
$conn = new PDO("mssql:host={$host};dbname={$db}", $user, $pass);
```

Which gives this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  
Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[0100] Unable to connect: SQL Server is unavailable or does not exist.  
Access denied. (severity 9)'
```

Second attempt (found on [experts-exchange](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Q_23833867%20experts%20exchange))

```
$conn = new PDO("odbc:Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server={$host};Database={$db};Uid={$user};Pwd={$pass}", 
                         $user, $pass);
```

This works, but I can't use `PDO::lastInsertId()`, which I would like to be able to:

```
 Driver does not support this function: driver does not support lastInsertId()
```

Do you have any suggestions? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm pretty sure that pdo with the mssql data server type requires dblib to connect. do you have dblib installed on the machine? make sure you can find ntwdblib.dll somewhere in the path on your system. i know this doesn't jive with the error message you're getting, but i'm not sure i trust the error message.

Answer (score 1):

I updated ntwdblib.dll as suggested [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2008/04/24/database_connection_php/) and it now works.

Unfortunately I still can't use `PDO::lastInsertId()` because apparently this driver does not support it either, so it wasn't really worth the hassle. I can however use the equivalent `SELECT @@IDENTITY as Id`.

Answer (score 0):

> That you cannot use SQL Server authentication because only Windows authentication is permitted.

Check if the server is [running Mixed mode authentication.](http://www.hostmysite.com/support/vps/windows/mixedmode/)

Also check if [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634197/zend-framework-and-sql-server) helps you.

Comment: Thanks for this. The other question didn't have a resolution though. It is running mixed mode because I can connect through SQL Server Management Studio either by using Windows Authentication or using a SQL Server login I created for the database.