# PHP SQL Server Access denies (severity 9)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have an old website that I am moving from an old server to a newer server. I have set up `php` and verified that it works and I have installed `Microsoft SQL Server` and migrated the old db and users. I am running `php-5.2.13` and `windows server 2008 r2`

I am having problems connecting to SQL.

```
<?php
mssql_connect('localhost', 'GeoTracker1', 'GeoTracker1');
?>
```

Gives me:

> ( ! ) Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect: SQL Server is unavailable or does not exist. Access denied. (severity 9) in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\geotracker\mssqlcheck.php on line 2
>
> Call Stack
>
> #
>
> Time
>
> Memory
>
> Function
>
> Location
>
> 1 0.0002 102608 {main}( ) ..\mssqlcheck.php:0 
>   2 0.0002 102808 mssql_connect ( ) ..\mssqlcheck.php:2
>
> ( ! ) Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server: localhost in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\geotracker\mssqlcheck.php on line 2
>
> Call Stack
>
> #
>
> Time
>
> Memory
>
> Function
>
> Location
>
> 1 0.0002 102608 {main}( ) ..\mssqlcheck.php:0 
>   2 0.0002 102808 mssql_connect ( ) ..\mssqlcheck.php:2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/797707/connect-to-sql-server-2008-with-pdo

Comment: sure the server is even running?

Comment: MS SQL Server says it is running. Do I need to install any extra dll? extension? or addons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable Named Pipes on your new SQL Server.